# Tcl.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, tcl

I'm trying to port some code over from a Solaris box onto a Linux (specifically Redhat) box. Code compiled without issues and ran without issues on the Solaris box.

However, in recompiling on Linux, I'm running into an issue with tcl.h - the compiler is telling me that `error: tcl.h: No such file or directory` for multiple files that `#include "tcl.h"`.

As far as I can tell, both tcl8.4 & tk8.4 are installed:

- /usr/lib/tcl8.4
- /usr/share/tcl8.4
- /usr/lib/tk8.4
- /usr/share/tk8.4

However, I can't find tcl.h anywhere. Does anyone know where it would be? Or is it one of those files that Solaris needed, but Linux does not need to be included? Or even do I need to install something in addition to tcl/tk 8.4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the development files for tcl installed (libraries are usually packaged separately from headers). Try:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep tcl
```

If it's not there, find the -devel package to install. If it is, it may be in a directory that the compiler isn't including. If it is installed, you should be able to find the file with rpm (I think the option is `-ql <packagename>`)

Answer (score 11):

You need to install the *development* package to get the header files. Depending on your Linux distribution, look for packages named like `tcl8.4-dev` and `tk8.4-dev`.

Comment: You can install apt-file and then do ``apt-file search '*/tcl.h'`` to see which package includes this file.

Comment: That's it. Good grief. You think you have everything you need and weeks later you're still missing critical items lol Thank you.

Comment: newbies - don't confuse libtclcl-dev with tcl-dev

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dnf makecache
sudo dnf install tcl-devel.x86_64
rpm -qa |grep tcl
```