# Installation of Transcriber (http://trans.sourceforge.net/en/install.php)

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

I am going around with no success in installing Transcriber in Ubuntu. Way very difficult :s

I follow all the steps the link above, but no way of passing this part of installing first the **tcltk** - ./configure --enable-gcc --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
make

It doesn't work and gives a bunch of errors. SO I decided to search and do as here, to install tcltk - [Install TCL/TK without root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163983/install-tcl-tk-without-root)

So I tried the code but it didn't work again, starting here sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/tcltk

It was saying I had no permissions in opt so I found a way to create a tcltk folder, fine, but when I put the sudo it comes:

`checking whether to use symlinks for manpages... no
checking whether to compress the manpages... no
checking whether to add a package name suffix for the manpages... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See`config.log' for more details.
`

I am tired of this guys, if you could please help me to install this I would be very thankful. I understand not that much of ubuntu. Thank you!

Comment: `sudo apt install build-essential` will install the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compile without a compiler (and linker). They're usually not very happy about being installed in user directories.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Alternatively, if you're just wanting to *run* Tcl code without installing, you can use [KitCreator](http://kitcreator.rkeene.org/kitcreator) to get your own single-file executable. (Yes, that site will build one for you While-U-Wait. The guy who wrote it isn't big on fancy CSS, even more so than me, but he does make good technology deployments.) There are other options too, but they're either older or less easy to use without being able to install compilers and so on.

Comment: this is just lovely :-)